# Startup time of webservice

Tags: web-services, iis

I have a WCF web service running in IIS. 
I do a lot of load work in the service constructor

```
namespace WcfService_MyService {

   [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)] 
   public class Service1 : IService1
   {
       public Service1()
       {
          Trace("Service starting");
          ...load work...
          Trace("Service ready to accept requests");
       }

       ... more functions...
   }
}
```

But sometimes the service is restarted when it hasn't finish to load yet.
I have log files and I see that the service is restarted.
I suppose it is because it takes about 7 seconds to start and I suppose because IIS thinks it is not responding so it creates a new one. Is this correct?

Can I tell IIS to wait longer?

I don't want to have a thread to do all the load because I don't want to accept requests until everything is loaded. And as I told you the loading process is long but it will never be more than 10 seconds.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: To check who killed it, enable WCF tracing. It is not likely to be IIS.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this web-service world. How can I do that?

Comment: Hope you are not new to the Internet, where Google returns this page, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you. There is always soooo much to read. I was hoping to have just a few magic steps to do that instead of staying a whole afternoon translating English. Thanks any way.

Comment: To enable tracing see the answer to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34989967/catching-all-unhandled-exceptions-in-wcf-web-service-in-c-sharp